# Difference between git subtree and git filter-banch

Tags: git

Is there any difference between these two commands?

```
git subtree split --prefix=some_subdir -b some_branch
```

and

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter some_subdir some_branch
```

I would like to use `git filter-branch` instead of `git subtree` because I also want to delete some files in the new branch, but I am worried that this guarantee, which is true for `git subtree`, might not be valid for `git filter-branch`:

> Repeated splits of exactly the same history are guaranteed to be
>   identical (ie. to produce the same commit ids).  Because of this, if
>   you add new commits and then re-split, the new commits will be
>   attached as commits on top of the history you generated last time, so
>   'git merge' and friends will work as expected.

Comment: I am deleting my answer.  I'll repost when I have more info.

Comment: I wish we had an answer to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter-branch` definitely does not give any such guarantee, so when using it you are definitely on the hoping side. But the subdirectory filter has exactly reproducible results and `filter-branch` does not touch the commit information (commit and author timestamp and person). As this is the information the commit sha is created from, `filter-branch` **should** generate the same history again.

That’s all you going to get as long as `filter-branch` does not start making any guarantees, and that seems unlikely.